# npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json

Tags: laravel, npm, cmd, pusher

I'm trying to install laravel echo using the command line `npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js`

Someone suggested me to install `node.js` but it still didn't work.

And gave me this result

> npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
>   + laravel-echo@1.5.3
>   + pusher-js@4.4.0
>   added 9 packages from 10 contributors and audited 9 packages in 22.504s
>   found 0 vulnerabilities

What do you think is the problem?

Comment: I don't think there *is* a problem, it added some packages and created a new file. Does your code work afterwards? As it suggests, you should commit the lockfile so that you get more consistent installations elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an error, it is just advising what to do with the file it has created. You can read more about this file [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json).